# Jquery Ajax & PHP - Return a Variable and PHP Page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, get, load

I have been successfully using jquery .load() to return a PHP page and load into a DIV.

I now need to alter this page load to check if the PHP Session is active and if not redirect to a different page using jquery (Note: I can't redirect using PHP redirect as this is the first load out of several that continue if this one PHP page is redirected).... thus a Jquery redirect is required.

I'm now using an AJAX GET to request/check if the Session is active (returning a variable) and then also want to return the PHP page if the session is active. Note: when I say session is active I mean 'logged on equals 1 rather then 0'.

The problem I have is I don't know how to return a PHP (or any) page from within PHP.

eg: Jquery to request session active status & php page is active.

```
$.get('scripts/ajax/ajax_banner_functions.php', {
    'loadBannerCheckSessionStatus': '1'},           
    function(data) {
        alert(data);
});
```

I can easily send a session ok variable back and jquery redirect if need - but how in PHP do I send a php file back? Do I convert a PHP file into a variable and send? Is there a better way to do this?

I guess i could do a $.get request for the session status and then a .load() to load the page but I want to try to do this in one ajax request.

:) thankyou

Comment: how does your .php file look like?

Comment: PHP file is mainly HTML with a couple of PHP statements in it... interesting you ask that... now I'm assuming the PHP statements might not execute if I load into a variable...

Comment: @Adam is that what you are trying to do below ? or have i misunderstood ?

Comment: I understand how to do a redirect - I'm trying to return a variable and PHP page in a jquery $.get request

Comment: @adam one ajax request only .. i have updated my answer please check .. hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*If i have understood correctly* then you are looking to do redirection of the user. There are 2 ways

1) ***Using PHP : ***

Use the `header` function like this in your php code

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
exit;`
```

2) **Using JS**: (I think you want this )

Depending on your applications logic use ajax or inbuilt logic to get url from your server and redirect using javascript `window.location` to redirect.
So send a request to the server. In the callback function check for your `session` variable data that is being sent. Then on successful request redirect using javascript. This would happen all in **one** request as you asked.

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to return the php of the file you could just dump your page to the output in your ajax call.

eg:

```
if ($_SESSION['LoggedOn'] == 1) {
    include "yourphpfile.php";
}
```

you could also return an error page if they are not logged in:

```
if ($_SESSION['LoggedOn'] == 1) {
    include "yourphpfile.php";
} else {
    include "notloggedinpage.php";
}
```